# Is there a way in which to recalculate a syms variable and insert it into an array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have to calculate the frictional head-loss, hf, for a pipe system, and am trying to write a simple script. I'm using the Colebrook-White & Darcy-Weisbach equation to solve for hf within a for loop and want the results inputted into an array.

This is what I've done so far:

```
%% Constants due to Rising main system
Hs = 17;        % m
D = 0.225;      % m
L = 1550;       % m
ks = 0.05/1000; % m
nu = 1.13e-6;   % m^2/s
Q = 0.08;       % m^3/s

%% Calculating hf for the system curve (DW)
Q_sys = [0:10:120];
hf_sys = zeros(1, length(Q_sys));
for i = 1:length(hf_sys)
    syms hf
    DW = Q_sys(i)==2*sqrt(2*9.81*D*hf/L)*log(ks/3.7/D+2.51*nu/D/sqrt(2*9.81*D*hf/L))*(pi*D^2/4);
    hf_sys(i) = vpasolve(DW, hf);
end
hf_sys % to display hf_sys
```

My problem is that after execution, the following message is displayed:

```
Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements.

Error in calcs (line 63)
    hf_sys(i) = vpasolve(DW, hf);
```

This is due to the return value of `vpasolve(DW, hf)` after the second iteration being `Empty sym: 0-by-1`. Which is what I'm trying to resolve.

The expected values are:

```
hf_sys = [5.5e-8, 0.481, 1.697, 3.585, 6.126, 9.308, 13.127, 17.579, 22.662, 28.374, 34.714, 41.681, 49.274];
```